# Uncompressed .lzo files in parallel and then delete the original .lzo files

Tags: shell, archive, parallelism

So I have `.lzo` files in `/test01/primary` folder which I need to uncompress and then delete all the `.lzo` files. Same thing I need to do in `/test02/secondary` folder as well. I will have around 150`.lzo` files in both folders so total around 300 files.

From a command line I was running like this to uncomressed one file `lzop -d file_name.lzo`
What is the fastest way to uncompressed all `.lzo` files and then delete all `.lzo` files from both folders. I came up with below code.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary

lzop -d $PRIMARY/* & lzop -d $SECONDARY/*
find $PRIMARY $SECONDARY -name '*.lzo' -delete
```

May be we can decompress the `.lzo` files in parallel and then delete all `.lzo` file in both the folders simultaneously to speed up the process.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the man page:

```
   -U, --unlink, --delete
              Delete input files after succesful compression or decompression.
```

so you could simply run

```sh
lzop -dU -- {"$PRIMARY","$SECONDARY"}/*.lzo
```

to delete each `lzo` file as soon as it's successfully decompressed.
`lzop` is single-threaded so if you want parallel processing you could use `gnu parallel`:

```sh
parallel lzop -dU -- ::: {"$PRIMARY","$SECONDARY"}/*.lzo
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have updated the question with details. You mean something like that? And that's all? It will delete automatically?

Comment: Will it uncompressed and delete in parallel in both the folders simultaneously? Or it will uncompressed PRIMARY first and then delete PRIMARY .lzo and then uncompressed SECONDARY and then delete SECONDARY .lzo?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to understand to see that's what you meant or something else. Ok gnu parallel looks fine.. Now let's say if I have 150 files in PRIMARY and 150 files in SECONDARY, then with your parallel suggestion it will start uncompressing and deleting on all 150 files both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY folder simultaneously? Or can we control like do 40 files at a time and then move to next 40? I am trying to see whether there will be any issue if it starts uncompressing and deleting on all 150 files both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY at same time.

Comment: @user1950349 - no, parallel processing doesn't mean _all_ your files will be processed simultaneously but as many as possible. Sure, you can fine tune it, see this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163890) by the author and read the manual & tutorial (linked in the same post).

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel spawns the jobs in the order they are given to GNU Parallel. So if you first list the $PRIMARY files and then the $SECONDARY files, then the $PRIMARY files will be processed first.

*Unless* `--shuf` is given. `--shuf` shuffles the arguments before running them. You will still not get one $PRIMARY file, then a $SECONDARY file every time, but at least the order will be random.

Comment: Thanks Ole for suggestion. I have opened another question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235144/uncompressed-lzo-files-in-parallel-in-both-the-folders-simultaneously-and-then) in which I am trying to paralelly uncompress and delete .lzo files both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY folders simultaneously but not able to make it work so far.