# Uncompressed .lzo files in parallel in both the folders simultaneously and then delete the original .lzo files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, archive, gnu-parallel

So I have `.lzo` files in `/test01/primary` folder which I need to uncompress and then delete all the `.lzo` files. Same thing I need to do in `/test02/secondary` folder as well. I will have around 150 `.lzo` files in both folders so total around 300 `.lzo` files.

From a command line I was running like this to uncomressed one file `lzop -d file_name.lzo`.

What is the fastest way to uncompressed all `.lzo` files and then delete all `.lzo` files from both folders simultaneously. Below is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary

parallel lzop -dU -- ::: {"$PRIMARY","$SECONDARY"}/*.lzo
```

I want to uncompress and delete `.lzo` files parallelly in both PRIMARY and SECONDARY folder simultaneously. With my above code, it does in PRIMARY first and then in SECONDARY folder. How can I achieve parallellism both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY simultaneously?

Also does it uncompress all the files and then delete later on or uncompress one file and then delete that file and then move to next one?

I tried with this but it doesn't work. It just works on first 40 files and after that it doesn't work at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary

parallel -j 40 lzop -dU -- ::: "$PRIMARY"/*.lzo &
parallel -j 40 lzop -dU -- ::: "$SECONDARY"/*.lzo &
wait
```

Comment: It deletes each _lzo_ file as soon as it has successfully decompressed it, it's in the manual excerpt in my answer to your other question.

Comment: aahh sure.. understood that part..

Comment: Why do you have 80 lzop processes running all at the same time?

Comment: I just came up with some number so started using 40. I want  to parallelly uncompressed and delete .lzo files both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY folder simultaneously so that's why I came up with that example.

Comment: Write a script, no shebang, just a file e.g. `p_script` with two lines:
`parallel lzop -dU -- ::: path1/*.lzo` and `parallel lzop -dU -- ::: path2/*.lzo`
make it executable and then run `parallel ::: ./p_script` (you should further optimize with `-j`...)

Comment: @don_crissti can I not have everything in one shell script and then run as `./script.sh`?

Comment: Well, nothing stopping you from doing something like e.g. : `printf '%s\n' 'parallel lzop -dU -- ::: dir1/*.lzo' 'parallel lzop -dU -- ::: dir2/*.lzo' | parallel -t -j2` or even `function unlzo { cd "$1" && parallel lzop -dU -- ::: ./*.lzo; }` and then `export -f unlzo` and `parallel -j2 unlzo ::: "$PRIMARY" "$SECONDARY"`... I'm not sure I fully understand the meaning of _achieve parallellism both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY simultaneously_  so this might not do what you actually want...

Comment: lzop is extremely fast. On a normal disk system the limit will be the writing to the disk. Have you measured that running multiple in parallel actually give a speed up? For elaboration see https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/

Comment: @OleTange Problem is my second script doesn't work. It just gets stopped. And also I am not sure which one I should use here? Should I go with first one or modified one of second script? As I need to do this both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY simultaneously.

Comment: @user1950349 Are you sure it stops? I tested on my system and because lzop is so fast, it looks as if the system does nothing. But what is really happening is that the disk system is being hit -- hard! So have a look and see if the files are really completely unpacked and see if it works better if you use -j1 instead of -j40. You have to have a very abnormal disk system if -j40 on lzop really speeds anything up.

Comment: What I saw with -j40, it uncompressed 40 files both in PRIMARY and SECONDARY fine but then it got stopped and it was not working on any other files. Not sure what happened and I waited for long time and it didn't move... So I was thinking may be my syntax was not right with the way I have two parallel lines each for PRIMARY and SECONDARY. Can you tell me whether my second script is correct in terms of the way we use gnu parallel? And yeah I can try with -j1 and see how does it look like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to parallelize both directories, but balance the load between (presumably) two storage devices?

The easiest solution is probably to interleave the file names in the input to parallel:

```bsh
paste -d'\n' <(ls "$PRIMARY"/*.lzo) <(ls "$SECONDARY"/*.lzo) | parallel lzop -dU --
```

- The `paste` command takes one line from each file and normally puts them side-by-side in an output file, but here we're using `\n` as the delimiter, so they end up with the lines interleaved.
- `<(...)` is bash syntax to "pipe" a command output into another command as if it were a file (I think it uses temporary named pipes), which allows us to pipe in two at once.
- parallel reads the filenames from stdin, if `:::` is not given, and runs one job per CPU if `-j` is not given. It will work its way down the input list in a linear manner, so the interleaving should spread the load how you want it.